# Can you perform Salagram puja in Sutaka/thudaku

Tags: vishnu, death, puja, prayaschitta, shaligrama

I had a question. I am initiated and perform Sri Salagrama Nitya Puja daily. I am under the instruction to do it daily. What do I do when there is a time of uncleanliness in the family. Do I need to stop worshipping him or is there something else I can do like Manasa puja to continuously worship Him. Also after the sutaka period do I need to do any prayascitta

Comment: During Sutak all Pujas should be stopped  Resume only after the end of that period.